# Concurrency vs Normal Collection?

Tags: c#, multithreading

so i have a question about the System.Collections.Concurrent

I saw that the Concurrent is acctually a safe thread collection, but in wich cases it can be helpfull?

I made 2 examples and the result are the same

First the ConcurrentQueue:

```
    static ConcurrentQueue<int> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
    private static readonly object obj = new object();
    static int i = 0;
    static int Num = 0;
    static void Run(object loopNum)
    {
        lock (obj)
        {
            for (int N = 0; N < 10; N++)
            {
                queue.Enqueue (i);
                Thread.Sleep(250);
                queue.TryDequeue(out Num);
                Console.WriteLine($"{Num} Added! in {loopNum} Loop, ThreadID: [{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}]");
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

And now the normal Queue:

```
    static Queue<int> queue = new Queue<int>();
    private static readonly object obj = new object();
    static int i = 0;

    static void Run(object loopNum)
    {
        lock (obj)
        {
            for (int N = 0; N < 10; N++)
            {
                queue.Enqueue (i);
                Thread.Sleep(250);
                Console.WriteLine($"{queue.Dequeue()} Added! in {loopNum} Loop, ThreadID: [{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}]");
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Main:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Thread[] Th = new Thread[] { new Thread(Run), new Thread(Run) };
        Th[0].Start("First");
        Th[1].Start("Second");


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The result are the same

Sure, it got some diffrent methods like TryDequeue And a few more, but what it really helpfull for?

Any help will be very appriciated :)

Comment: Useful when the collection is accessed concurrently on many threads.

Comment: When trying to measure the time difference between different threadsafe mechanisms, adding a delay of 250ms will probably exceed that difference by some orders of magnitude...

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `lock()` in conjunction with `ConcurrentQueue<>` or similar items in that namespace.  It's detrimental to performance.

You can use `ConcurrentQueue<>` safely with multiple threads and have great performance.  The same can not be said with `lock()` and regular collections.

That's why your results are the same.

Comment: Note that the other code accessing shared resources must also be made thread-safe - in this case, replacing `i++` with `Interlocked.Increment(ref i)` will do the trick. And of course, the 250ms wait in the `Thread.Sleep` will likely dwarf any performance difference of two threads using a simple queue... Adding more threads and getting rid of the `Thread.Sleep` will paint a clearer picture.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for using `ConcurrentQueue<T>` is to avoid writing your own locking code.

If you have multiple threads adding or removing items from a `Queue<T>` you are likely to get an exception. Using a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` will avoid the exceptions.

Here's a sample program which will likely cause an exception when using multiple threads to write to a `Queue<T>` while it works with a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var queue1 = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
        var queue2 = new Queue<int>();

        // This will work fine.

        var task1 = Task.Run(() => producer(item => queue1.Enqueue(item)));
        var task2 = Task.Run(() => producer(item => queue1.Enqueue(item)));

        Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);

        // This will cause an exception.

        var task3 = Task.Run(() => producer(item => queue2.Enqueue(item)));
        var task4 = Task.Run(() => producer(item => queue2.Enqueue(item)));

        Task.WaitAll(task3, task4);
    }

    private static void producer(Action<int> add)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
            add(i);
    }
}
```

Try running it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the `lock` construct, your code effectively executes in sequence, not in parallel. This solution is suitable for the version with simple `Queue` as it's not thread-safe, but with `ConcurrentQueue`, using `lock` kinda defeats the purpose. Remove the lock for `ConcurrentQueue`, remove the `Thread.Sleep`, and use 20 threads instead of 2 just for kicks. You can use `Parallel.For()` method to spawn your tasks.

```
Parallel.For(0, 20, i => Run());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for all your answers, really helped me out, i appriciate it alot.

By the way Matthew Watson, your example sometimes give's an exception and sometime's isnt, i made a better example, but yeah i get the point.

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        var queue1 = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
        var queue2 = new Queue<int>();

        // This will work fine.

        var task1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 40)
            .Select(_ => Task.Run(() => producer(item => queue1.Enqueue(item))))
            .ToArray();

        Task.WaitAll(task1);

        // This will cause an exception.

        var task2 = Enumerable.Range(0, 40)
                        .Select(_ => Task.Run(() => producer(item => queue2.Enqueue(item))))
                        .ToArray();

        Task.WaitAll(task2);
    }
```

Thanks again :)